# C++ Comparing two values in an array and getting subscript number of the greater

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compare the values in an array after passing it to a function and return the subscript of the element with the greatest value to represent a month of the year(ex: Jan = 1, Feb = 2, ect.). I've fiddled around with my algorithm but I just can't seem to get it to work. I (think) I know what I should do. Can someone explain this to me simply? (beginner in programming). Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//this program determines the most wet and dry months
//in a year and calculates the annual rainfall and monthly average

//function declarations
double calculateTotal(double [], int);
double calculateAvg(double, int);
int determineWetMonth(double [], int);
int determineDryMonth(double [], int);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    double months[SIZE];//array stores rainfall each month

    //initialize array
    for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        months[count] = 0;
        }

    //populate array
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        int rain = 0;
        cout << "Enter the rainfall for month: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> rain;
        months[i] = rain;
            }



    //call total function
    double total = 0.0;
    total = calculateTotal(months, SIZE);

    //call average function
    double avg = 0.0;
    avg = calculateAvg(total, SIZE);

    //call wet function
    int highest = 0;
    highest = determineWetMonth(months, SIZE);

    //call dry function
    int lowest = 0;
    lowest = determineDryMonth(months, SIZE);

    //display results
    cout << "The total annual rainfall is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "The average monthly rainfall is: " << avg << endl;
    cout << "The WETTEST month is: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "The DRYEST month is: " << lowest;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

}

double calculateTotal(double anArray[], int size)
{
    double theTotal = 0.0;
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        theTotal = theTotal + anArray[j];
        }
    return theTotal;
    }

double calculateAvg(double someTotal, int amount)
{
    double theAvg = 0.0;
    theAvg = someTotal / amount;
    return theAvg;
    }

int determineWetMonth(double theArray[], int num)
{
    int most = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < num; k++)
    {
        if(theArray[k] > theArray[0])
        {
            most = k+1;
            }
        }
    return most;
    }   

int determineDryMonth(double ourArray[], int dec)
{
    int least = 0;
    for(int m = 0; m < dec; m++)
    {
        if(ourArray[m+1] < ourArray[m])
        {
            least = m+1;
            }
        }
    return least;
    }
```

Comment: In your `determineWetMonth` function you have wrong logic where you have `if(theArray[k] > theArray[0])` thats wrong because your always comparing it to be the first value in the array and not necessarly the current biggest. You should be comparing it to `most-1` so it should look like `if(theArray[k] > theArray[most-1])`

Comment: @JackV So I should be comparing the value of the current element to the value stored in element before it? (since its [most-1])

Comment: No you should be comparing the value of the current element with the value of the current largest element

Comment: Oh! I see now! Because if I just compared each element to the element before it instead of the largest one, the "largest" would always be the greater of the two that I compared, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the value of the largest/smallest value

```
int determineWetMonth(double theArray[], int num)
{
    int most = 1;
    for(int k = 1; k < num; k++)
    {
        if(theArray[k] > theArray[most-1])
        {
            most = k+1;
        }
    }
    return most;
}   

int determineDryMonth(double ourArray[], int dec)
{
    int least = 1;
    for(int m = 1; m < dec; m++)
    {
        if(ourArray[m] < ourArray[least-1])
        {
            least = m+1;
        }
    }
    return least;
}
```

Comment: So I compare the value of an element to the value of the element before it?

Comment: No. You're looking for the maximum/minimum. You compare the current element to the current maximum/minimum. See code above. If you don't understand the logic, try writing out the values manually for a few loops to see what is going on.

Comment: Good idea, I'll deskcheck this now with a few loops as you suggested this come back with another question if I have one.

Comment: Okay I've deskchecked halfway through the array using the values {25, 36, 82, 91, 12, 6, 15, 27, 55, 46, 31, 70};. What I see going on is during the first iteration I'm comparing whatever is in the current element being checked [0] to the value of the expression [most-1] which evaulates to -1 first. Since there's no sub -1, this evaluates to True, and the subscript of the element with the highest value is set to 0. Then I repeat for the remaining elements. Did I comprehend that right?

Comment: No. The variable **most** starts at 1, so **most-1** evaluates to 0. The index **k** starts from 1 and goes to **num-1**. Recheck the initial values and iteration ranges. How about instead of writing the values manually, insert print statements as the code is running.

Comment: I followed your advice with the printing and I got some numbers as results.    2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4. I'm assuming each number means that is the number of the month with the current maximum value?

Comment: I don't know what you printed. However, clearly the 4th entry is the largest value 91.

Comment: I added a print statement after the closing bracket of the If clause to get those numbers.

Comment: Then, yes. That looks like the correct output. If your happy with the code then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you having patience with me and helping me with this. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, that's what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ solution using algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int determineDryMonth(double* ourArray, int siz)
{
    return std::distance(ourArray, std::min_element(ourArray, ourArray + siz));
} 

int determineWetMonth(double* theArray, int num)
{
    return std::distance(theArray, std::max_element(theArray, theArray + num));
}
```

The `min_element` returns a pointer to the smallest item in the range, and the `distance` function tells you how far away the start is from the returned pointer.  In essence, you get the position of the smallest value.

For the wettest month, the only change is that the function to get a pointer to the largest value is `std::max_element`.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I'll remember it for the future, but for now we're only allowed to use what we've covered in class, so I can't use that unfortunately.

Comment: Well I don't know what you covered in class.  But my answer is for someone searching for such a solution (using the algorithm functions).